# Convert string to Date with zone in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am having a trouble with converting string to date object,

this is my string

```
dt='Fri Mar 29 2013 14:30:00 GMT 0530 (IST)' ;
```

i want to convert it to

```
2013-03-29 09:00:00
```

How can i do that ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that have to subtract the 5.5 hours from time. To do so have to convert it to a time object, then must subtract the time. Then have to to convert it again. A simple point. But i missed it.

```
time = Time.parse(time_string)
my_time = (time - 5.5*60*60).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
Time.parse(string).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s')
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html
has plenty of info for how to format the output etc.

Comment: this is the out put from above function, 2013-03-29 Mar:03:136451522, but it not which i want

Comment: then i changed it to 'Date.parse(from_date).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')' now its return '2013-03-29 00:00:00', also not i am expecting

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy in ruby:

```
require 'time'
Time.parse('Fri Mar 29 2013 14:30:00 GMT 0530 (IST)').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S')
```

Comment: Stops from where? Btw, I updated my answer to give exactly the format you wanted